# Using os.path.relpath on Windows network drive

Tags: python, windows, path, relative-path, network-drive

I need to get the relative path on a network drive. So, from `s:\path\to\file`, I want to get `path\to\file`.

So, this works:

```py
In [8]: path = r's:\path\to\file'

In [9]: path[3:]
Out[9]: 'path\\to\\file'
```

But I thought that using `os.path.relpath()` was a smarter, more pythonic way. This doesn't work though:

```py
In [10]: os.path.relpath(r's:\path\to\file')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 1
----> 1 os.path.relpath(r's:\path\to\file')

File <frozen ntpath>:758, in relpath(path, start)

ValueError: path is on mount 's:', start on mount 'C:'
```

Is there any workaround to allow the use of `relpath` on network drives?

Comment: This is not related to network drives. `relpath` raises the exception because of different drive letters (as documentation says). In such a case `relpath` can't do anything for you anyway and you have to use the full path.

Comment: `os.path.splitdrive` is more helpful.

Comment: Indeed, this yields the expected result: `os.path.relpath(path, os.path.splitdrive(path)[0])`. Thank you!